# Performance of ASK and SELECT queries in SPARQL

Tags: select, sparql, rdf

I started using SPARQL queries on an RDF dataset, and I wanted to know whether there's a difference (time consumption) between `SELECT` queries and `ASK` queries, given the same constraints.

To be more precise: I don't really need the results but I need just to check if there's data which satisfies my constraints or no;
That is why I'm asking whether it would be better to use `ASK` or `SELECT` queries (regarding performance).

Comment: should not really matter, if you'd use a `LIMIT n` with small `n`. For me `ASK` is basically the same like `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` - in both queries, an optimizer might benefit from a restriction of the number of results. Indeed, without a `LIMIT` the `SELECT` query can be slower because complete result as well as intermediate results to get to the final result can be much larger and therefore more time-consuming. But a general statement is difficult, it totally depends on the query pattern - just my two cents, unfortunately, I'm not a triple store developer

Comment: Can you clarify why you're asking? If you just need to know whether something exists, sure use `ASK` to get a boolean value. it also reduces the traffic overhead if you use it via HTTP

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am still looking it up, to clarify; it is just to make sure that a given answer is available in the dataset, I don't really need to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need to know if *any* solution in the endpoint would satisfy the query, `ASK` is the verb to use. There are various reasons why *some* `SELECT` queries might return (some) result(s) faster than the parallel `ASK`, but overall `ASK` will be faster.